# Subir cambios a Gh-Pages desde consola

Tags: git-push, github-pages

Tengo un repositorio ya creado en github donde publique un proyecto por gh-pages. Haciendo pruebas en resoluciones veo necesario hacer ajustes en el css pero al entrar en la rama y pushear los cambios, no se guardan!? ... que ... estaría pasando?

Comment: ¿Segura que cambiaste de rama al pushear?

Answer (score 0):

En todo versionador, ya sea de archivos binarios o texto plano, es obligatorio:

- Commit = guardar cambios locales.
- pull = bajar cambios
- push = subir cambios

yo trabajo con git, y uso gitlab los comandos de github son los mismos, así que prueba con eso commit, pull y push, créeme seguir estos pasos soluciona ese tipo de problemas, desde terminal puedes hacer commit de esta manera:

```
commit -m "el comentario de tus cambios."
```